# Only allow whole number in field

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, fields

If a field is of type Number(18,0) and you try to enter say 4.4 then it will truncate the decimal and save 4. Is there a way to alert the user that they are entering an invalid number. This seems like something that should be easy to do.

Comment: in a visualforce page? lightning-component? where exactly are you prompting your users to do so?

Comment: The user would be entering this information on the Salesforce object page layouts. I know how I would go about doing this in code but was wondering if there is a declarative  way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a validation rule:

```
FLOOR(Field__c) <> Field
```

Keep in mind that normally, the system stores exactly what the user entered, despite not showing it on the screen. So, for example, if they put in 9.9, it would show as 10, but if you did math with it, you'd get some apparent rounding errors. In other words, the Number(18,0) is actually a display value, not the actual underlying data type, so a validation rule like this can help keep your data clean.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are actually pretty limited. The first one is to leave it as is, and once the user saves the record he will see his number truncated. It's not "perfect", but it isn't a huge deal tho - take into account that sometimes developing something that takes multiple hours isn't worth the business value.

Declaratively speaking, you have no way of "warning" the user to not input decimal numbers. You can, however, **add a small message in the "help" section** of the field so the user can hover over it and see. Apart from that, you would have to make a visualforce/component or something else.

By the way, as a heads up, **take into account that the number isn't truncated but rounded up**, so if you input 3,8, it will save 4.

Cheers!